# Windows 8 Metro Applications not working

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I have been using Windows 8 now for the past 2 weeks, and have had some interesting experiences with it. At first, nothing on it worked, but after uninstalling Lenovo One Key Theater, and it worked again for a bit. But then the metro apps stopped working, but after uninstalling Kaspersky, they started working again.

But now it is doing it again. Whenever I try to open a metro app, the app screen comes up (lets use store as an example), but the icon and the spinner move from the centre of the screen to the top left, and just spins on for ever and never loads, does anyone know what could be causing it, or at least how to check it?

Out of interest, the camera app still works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, found the issue. Kaspersky was somehow re-installed. Possibly during one of the rollbacks that was forced on me when visual studio wouldn't install properly (smiley face of death popping up before login). But I had tried reinstalling my video drivers too (from the laptop vendors site), which fixed another irritation I was having, so great news everywhere

Answer (score 1):

Please run the **[Windows Store Apps](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=271185)** troubleshooter and look if it can detect and fix issues.

Here are also some information on how to fix issues with apps:

**[What to do if you have problems with an app](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/what-troubleshoot-problems-app)**

Comment: The only message the troubleshooter can up with was that a display adapter driver may be out of date, but after checking, they're fine. And as for `what to do if you have a problem with an app`, sadly not very helpful as I can't even open the store

Comment: Run this Powershell command and look at the output: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856039.aspx What do you see? Which errors do you get?

Comment: Not sure if there are any errors, but there are 6 entries, all within 75 seconds of each other, with no message

Comment: copy the output in a text file and upload it.

Comment: `Time                      ID           Message` 
`----                      --           -------` 
`18/11/2012 06:38:16       301` 
`18/11/2012 06:38:16       603` 
`18/11/2012 06:38:42       157` 
`18/11/2012 06:38:42       170` 
`18/11/2012 06:38:42       10002` 
`18/11/2012 06:39:25       400`

Comment: this is all you see?

Comment: that's all. But I have fixed the issue now, its in another answer

Comment: ok, I've overlooked this. Nice to see that you found the cause.